# how to determine which link in django template is causing NoReverseMatch error

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have hundreds of reverse links in my template that looking like this:

```
{% 'tracking:area' pk='1' %}
```

On one of them there is an invalid reference and I get the error:

> Reverse for 'area' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk':
>   ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'tracking/area/(?P\d+)/$']

How can I figure out which one is causing the problem from the hundreds in the template?

Comment: Paste the full track stace it should show which line in the template

Comment: Show pattern url for area